# Accessing abstract nested class in java

Tags: java, class, nested, abstract

Suppose I have a class say A which is an ordinary class.

Now A nests a class B , which in turn nests C.

Class B is an abstract class while A,C are not so.

Now, No object can be created for B as it is an abstract class.

But Unless i create an object for class B , i wont be able to create an object for class C.
since ,

```
outerclass out=new outerclass();
outerclass.innerlcass in=outerclass.new innerclass();
```

Since B has no object , the outerclass object "out" is not available in this case.

So how do I create an object for C?

Comment: Make C a static class, then you wil be able to access it as B.new C()

Comment: does it really a usecase or a fictitious example?

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
public class A {
    abstract class B {
        abstract String get();
        class C {
            void run() {
                System.out.println(get());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().new B(){ String get() { return "hi"; } }.new C().run();
    }
}
```

Or alternately, with the same A, B, and C as above:

```
class ConcreteB extends B {
    String get() {
        return "I'm not anonymous!";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new A().new ConcreteB().new C().run();
}
```

Comment: With this implementation, one needs to provide implementation for all the 'abstract' methods in class B

Comment: @rahulroc: Naturally, which is why I did in both examples.

Comment: Hence, I think the solution which I provided in the comment in the question may be a better solution provided he can change the Class definition.

Comment: @rahulroc: Maybe, but that also assumes that C doesn't need an enclosing B instance, like it does in my example.